# How can I get right content to stack in the footer?

Tags: css

How can I get the two divs on the right side of the footer to stack on each other while being justified right using only CSS or SCSS?

Here is what I have so far: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxqZwR

```css
footer {
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 18px 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
footer ol {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
footer ol li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
}
footer .footer-image {
  background: url("http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 80px;
  left: 0;
  width: 90px;
  margin-right: auto;
}
footer div:not(.footer-image) {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
 <footer>
 <div class="footer-image"></div>
 <div>
   <ol>
    <li><a href="#">Hot Potato</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Potato</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Potato</a></li>
   </ol>
 </div>
 <div>Some other text...</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Simply wrap the two inside another div?

Comment: Need to start reading questions better.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something like what you wanted? I moved the div with the text into the one with the list and used text-align:right to align the items.

```css
footer {
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 18px 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
footer ol {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
footer ol li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
}
footer .footer-image {
  background: url("http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 80px;
  left: 0;
  width: 90px;
  margin-right: auto;
}
footer div:not(.footer-image) {
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<footer>
 <div class="footer-image"></div>
 <div>
   <ol>
    <li><a href="#">Hot Potato</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Potato</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Potato</a></li>
   </ol>
   <div>Some other text...</div>
 </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! Curious though, if you were not allowed to alter the html at all (so it's the code provided here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QxqZwR), how would you go about styling it in CSS?

Comment: @Kalani Can you open a new question for that?